# Compare and partly merge multiple projects without common ancestor

Tags: sync, merge, comparison, diff, file-comparison

I'm looking for a way to compare/diff 3+ different, strongly related projects, none of which is the others' common ancestor and copy around ("merge") single chunks,
and specifically test files.

I do **not** want one single merged output, but keep all of them and just sort of synchronize single hand-chosen parts.

Comment: What is the environment?

Comment: I'm on Windows but wouldn't mind spinning up a linux VM.

Comment: You don't give any information about your tools (projects of what) and more information about your setup. Your post is being voted for closing, because it's unclear. I'm only trying to help.

Comment: It's about code, so mainly text files. This is not necessarily about specific tools that allow just that, maybe there are workflows with git or so. But I did try some tools. ECMerge displays the diffs for file trees/directories and files themselves very nicely, but doesn't allow inline editing. Diffuse allows inline editing but doesn't support directories, but only single files and text buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparing text files under Windows, the best tool is probably
[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en).

This allows the comparison of 2 or 3 files, the transfer of modification blocks
from one to the other, as well as the direct editing of the text.

WinMerge can detect a changed sequence of lines and handle it as one entity
that can be updated with a click or a hotkey.
It also has extensive options for comparing and executing.

**Open dialog:**

[image]

**Compare/merge workspace:**

[image]

Comment: AFAIK I can only compare two different versions with WinMerge. I'd love to be wrong about this: Can you add to your answer how you can compare 3+ different versions/snapshots w/ WinMerge?

Comment: Ok, turns out the [WinMergeJP](https://winmergejp.bitbucket.io/) fork supports three-way comparisons.
I still have to check though how well they work and if they work with the "ancestor mental model" or allow to compare three states independently

Comment: So does the normal one - I added better screenshots.

Comment: Wow, that's great news, thanks! Turns out 5 years after the last WinMerge release the JP fork has now been made the new official version ([Issue](https://bitbucket.org/winmerge/winmerge/issues/84/), [Official Announcement](https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/news/2018/01/a-sign-of-life-from-winmerge/), [Release Announcement](https://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/news/2018/11/winmerge-2160-stable-released/)). Thanks a ton, I wouldn't have noticed (or updated)

Comment: What I'd still love to see is a) support for more than 3 versions, b) being able to have aligned trees/panes for each version in the folder comparison, like [ECMerge has](http://www.elliecomputing.com/en/Products/ecmerge-compare-folders.asp) and c) having files and folders color coded with one color per matching version, like [HashMyFiles](http://hashmyfiles.findmysoft.com/screenshot/) and [N-way Folder Diff](https://sourceforge.net/projects/n-wayfolderdiff/) do, but I guess so far WinMerge is the best I'll get.

Comment: Funny how I've looked into dozens of tools, but the one I've been using for more than a decade is the one that just recently got that feature.